# Access imported functions from evaled code

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, eval, javascript-import

I have a TypeScript file with the following code:

```
import { functionTest } from './function_test'

function runnerFunctionTest() {
    console.log("Test");
}

export class Runner {
    run(source : string) {
        eval(source);
    }
}
```

If I instantiate a `Runner` and call `run("runnerFunctionTest();")` the function runs correctly, but if I call `run("functionTest();")` (which should run the imported function) I get an error saying `functionTest` is undefined.

How can I fix this?

One thing I tried was replacing the code in `run` with `new Function('functionTest', source).(functionTest);` which worked but it will be really annoying to have to add all the imported functions like that - there are around 20 of them and that number will only increase as time goes on.

Also, I am aware of the security implications of calling `eval` - it is the only way (at least that I know of) to do what I want, which is running arbitrary JavaScript code generated by the user in the user's browser.

Comment: Should run() not accept a callback function as a parameter? Why is source of type string if you are taking in functions.

Comment: @scottwsmyth it is supposed to run code from a string, it is generated by something else in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `import` is not a native operator, webpack (or something else) transform it for you.
After compiled by webpack, you code becomes:

```js
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "Runner", function() { return Runner; });
/* harmony import */ var _function_test__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(2);

function runnerFunctionTest() {
    console.log("Test");
}

class Runner {
    run(source) {
        eval(source);
    }
}
```

The name `functionTest` is not existed anymore, that why you can't eval it.

One possible solution is to give it a local name:

```js
import { functionTest } from './function_test'
const function_test = functionTest;
function runnerFunctionTest() {
    console.log("Test");
}

export class Runner {
    run(source : string) {
        eval(source);
    }
}
```

Then you can run `runner.run('function_test()')`